# "Have you fell in love" or "Have you fallen in love"

Tags: grammar

Can someone please explain to me which is the correct statement between the two? "Have you fell in love with someone who's shorter than you?" Or "Have you fallen in love with someone who's shorter than you?"

Answer (score 2):

"Fell" is the past tense of "fall", and "fallen" is the past participle of "fall", so in your sentences, "have you fallen in love" right because you use the present perfect here.